# Python3 for loop with multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a problem with my multiprocessing module. I want to iterate over a dict with a for loop and the processes should do a job for every dictitem. What's the best way to do this with multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pretty understandable examples in [the documentation of the multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). The following code is based on the first one, `f()` is the function that You execute for every dict item:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return (x[0], x[1]*x[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
    print list(d.iteritems())
    print(p.map(f, d.iteritems()))
```

returns:

```
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 9), ('b', 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thats exactly what i'm searching for!